# Gitlab Runner register local network (401)

Tags: git, server, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to register my Gitlab runner with an local network IP, because my Gitlab_ee(176.0.1.7) and also the Gitlab-Runner(176.0.1.3), share the same local network (176.0.1.*/16).

Problem is when i run:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register   
--url http://176.0.1.7 
--registration-token GR12345678_1234abcde   
--executor "shell"   
--description "rails-runner"  
--maintenance-note "rails-runner is currently in maintenance"   
--tag-list "rails, debian-11"   
--run-untagged="true"
```

I receive this:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=GR123456789 status=GET https://<domain>:443/api/v4/runners: 401 Unauthorized
PANIC: Failed to register the runner.
```

I not quit sure why this is happening, because the used domain is the right one and everything else looks also quiet promising.

I also checked, if the request reaches the Gitlab_ee Server with `httpry`:

```
# sudo httpry -i enp7s0

Starting capture on enp7s0 interface
2023-02-14 08:24:48 176.0.1.3   176.0.1.7   >   POST    176.0.1.7   /api/v4/runners HTTP/1.1    -   -
2023-02-14 08:24:48 176.0.1.7   176.0.1.3   <   -   -   -   HTTP/1.1    301 Moved Permanently
```

The request gets redirected, but i have to confess that i not sure whats happening afterwards.

When i just run the register with the `https://<domain>/` everything works just fine and the runner gets registered but with his public Ip and i dont want them to communicate trough the Internet just for safety reasons. I the entire Gitlab documentation i found nothing about registrating runners with in an local network. I also tried to disable the eth0 interface and running the register, but big surprise i couldn't reach the Gitlab_ee server.

I will try my best to finde a way to get it working, when i do i will post a solution below this post, but if anyone had the same problem and solved or just has a good idea i would like to hear it.

### Solution:

After Reaz Murshed comment I added this to my /etc/hosts

```
176.0.1.7  git.git-local.com # use your URL
```

afterwards I run the

```
sudo gitlab-runner register   
--url https://git.git-local.com/
--registration-token GR12345678_1234abcde   
--executor "shell"   
--description "rails-runner"  
--maintenance-note "rails-runner is currently in maintenance"   
--tag-list "rails, debian-11"   
--run-untagged="true"
```

and everything works fine. Gitlab shows me the correct local IP, as the registered IP. I am very happy and thank you very much Reaz Murshed for your comment it helped me a lot, even when its was kinda easy, I wouldent have thought about it, so thanks.^^

Comment: Just wondering if we could try adding an entry in the hosts, `/etc/hosts` file (e.g. `gitlab-local 176.0.1.7`) and then try registering the runner using `sudo gitlab-runner register   
--url gitlab-local .... rest of the params`.

Comment: That Sounds actually quiet good. I will try it this evening. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Cool! Let me know. Will post as an answer if that works! :D

Comment: And please post an answer, i think there will be other people trying to get it work to. I will instantly upvote your answer :)

Comment: I edited my question already with the solution, but please Reaz Murshed, post the solution, so I  and other people can upvote it.